# can I get shareobject file Path in FLASH?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, share

I  want  to  get shareobject file  path, and  then  actionscript3  call  javascript  to  copy this  file.
  how can I get  shareobject files's  real path  in  AS3 ?

Comment: Javascript can't copy a file on the HD... that's just security.

Answer (score 0):

The path of shareobject is like this in windows

```
%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\
```

And you can find paths of different OS in this [location of shareobject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object#File_locations)

Comment: This isn't exactly true. If the user is using Chrome and hasn't changed from the awful Pepper Flash plugin, the location is different. Additionally, the path is dynamic in Adobe AIR apps, relating to the app's ID. From a programatic standpoint, I don't believe it is possible to get the location for a browser-based SWF (not that it would do any good, given that there is no way to access the filesystem via the browser anyway).